# Overflowed text when printing in pdf in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, pdf-generation

I have two divs that printed to pdf by clicking a button:

```
var newWin = window.frames["print_frame"];
        newWin.document.write('<head><link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="Content/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="Content/printFixes.css?v=1.0.1.5" type="text/css"/></head><body onload="window.print()">' + $('#containerpdf').wrap('<div/>').parent().html() + '</body>');
        newWin.document.close();
```

In pdf, it looks like this(div one and two):

[image]

Those divs are in fact html editors, I just removed all the styles of the editor tool so it can ben shown correctly when printing.
So my question is, is there a way to put the overflowed text from (1) to be continued on (2); also put the overflowed text from (2) so it can be displayed from side to side on the second page? Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried putting column-count:2 into your css?

Comment: Oh I've never heard about that property. how I can use it in this case?